# Firefox extension - how to click button by Class and Title?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon

I have a Firefox extension that clicks something, and the code responsible for the actual click is this:

```
function xxBtn(){
  var btn = document.querySelector('button.ooo-qqq-vvv')
  if( !btn ){ return }
  btn.click()
}
```

The code it's clicking on is this:

```
<button class="ooo-qqq-vvv zzz-ttt" aria-label="One (k)" title="One (p)">
```

How can I make it so that it only clicks if BOTH the "class" and "title" elements are true?

So let's say we have these three on the page:

```
<button class="ooo-qqq-vvv zzz-ttt" aria-label="One (k)" title="One (p)">
<button class="ooo-qqq-vvv zzz-ttt" aria-label="One (k)" title="Two (p)">
<button class="ooo-qqq-vvv zzz-ttt" aria-label="One (k)" title="Three (p)">
```

I only want the click to happen on the first one. So I need both the class and title to be true for a click to occur. The way it works right now is it clicks by class, and it will click all of them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 var btn = document.querySelector('.ooo-qqq-vvv.zzz-ttt[title="Two (p)"]')
```

For further reference you can read the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) documentation.